# ¿Como especifico a un programa (C++) que debe buscar las librerías en una carpeta específica y no en la carpeta System32?

Tags: c++, compilar

Buenas Noches/Tardes/Días,

Os extiendo un poco por aquí la pregunta que os lanzo...

La cosa es que estoy creando un programa con C++ (en Visual Studio Community) y cuando lo compilo/ejecuto todo va como la seda puesto que en el system32 tengo las librerías necesarias.

Ahora bien, cuando ejecuto el mismo programa en otro ordenador que no tiene esas librerías (obviamente) sale el típico error de que falta "x.dll".

A raíz de esto, quiero guardar los dll necesarios en una carpeta junto al programa, y cuando éste se ejecute que busque en esa carpeta y no en el system32.

Comment: Diría que si guardas en la misma carpeta el ejecutable y las DLL el propio programa ya se encargará de usarlas. Otra cosa es que las DLL no estén ni en una ruta definida en el path, ni en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable, en cuyo caso tendrás que agregarla al path (busca en google "agregar carpeta al path")

Comment: Buenas, me sirve, muchas gracias @user3733164. Si quieres ponlo como respuesta y te voto positivamente. Los que estamos aprendiendo desde 0 esto nos es un poco difícil :'). Repito, muchas gracias.

Comment: No te preocupes, con responder en el comentario es suficiente. Puntúa si quieres estos comentarios :-)